# How do I convert a String to an integer in Rust?

Tags: rust

Reading input from stdin produces a `String`, but how do I convert it to an integer?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Type something");

    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("{}", input);
}
```

Comment: You should read the excellent Rust Book, which [specifically covers reading a number from standard input](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`parse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse):

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Type something");

    let mut line = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut line)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let input: u32 = line
        .trim()
        .parse()
        .expect("Wanted a number");

    println!("{}", input);
}
```

Note that parsing a number from a string can fail, so a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) is returned. For this example, we panic on a failure case using [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect).

Additionally, `read_line` leaves the newline from pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) is used to ignore that before parsing.

Comment: Sidenote: you can call parse on an `&str` to get any type `T` as long as `T` implements the trait `FromStr`.